# Consolidated RegEx to parse syslog data

Tags: regex, regex-group

#### Goal

I am trying to craft a RegEx that will parse out specific data from various syslog entries that contain subtle differences in logged content.  While I am able to accomplish my goal using multiple RegEx statements, if possible, I would like to combine these statements into a single consolidated RegEx.

---

#### Log entries

The main issue I'm having is that some log entries have a URL that needs to be parsed to a named group and other log entries do not have any URL.  Examples of these two different log entries are provided below.

##### Entry with URL

```
Nov  3 11:33:04 host1 postfix/smtpd[12812]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 178.red-83-59-180.dynamicip.rima-tde.net[83.59.180.178]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [83.59.180.178] blocked using b.barracudacentral.org; http://www.barracudanetworks.com/reputation/?pr=1&ip=83.59.180.178; from=<lmclapp68@newmail.spamcop.net> to=<user1@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<178.red-83-59-180.dynamicip.rima-tde.net>
```

##### Entry without URL

```
Nov  2 16:01:25 host1 postfix/smtpd[31667]: NOQUEUE: reject_warning: RCPT from mail1.sendersrv.com[185.3.229.125]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [185.3.229.125] blocked using bl.spamcop.net; from=<bounces+rL59wUXq98_inBrG@sendersrv.com> to=<user1@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail1.sendersrv.com>
```

---

#### RegEx statements

In the RegEx statements that follow, the first two are what I currently use for each of the previous log messages.  The third RegEx is my attempt at consolidating these both into a single RegEx that will parse data from either log message.  My attempt was to use a conditional statement that would basically check for the existence of `http(s)` and if found, then to parse the URL to a named group.  If `http(s)` was not found, then it would parse out everything until the next RegEx token.

The issue is that when I test the RegEx against a log entry that has a URL, the RegEx does not seem to find `http(s)` despite this token being set as optional (i.e. using the `?` quantifier).  However, if I remove the `?` quantifier, it does find `http(s)` and then parses the URL as desired.  However, without the quantifier, the RegEx does not work with log entries that do not have a URL.

##### Parse entries with URL

```
^(?P<datetime>.+) host1 postfix.+RCPT from (?P<srcDns>.+)\[(?P<srcIp>[0-9\.]+)\]:.+blocked using (?P<blkList>.+);.+https?:\/{2}(?P<entryUrl>.+);\s.+\sto=\<(?P<destEm>.+)>.+$
```

##### Parse entries without URL

```
^(?P<datetime>.+) host1 postfix.+RCPT from (?P<srcDns>.+)\[(?P<srcIp>[0-9\.]+)\]:.+blocked using (?P<blkList>.+);\s.+\sto=\<(?P<destEm>.+)>.+$
```

##### Attempt at consolidating RegEx

```
^(?P<datetime>.+) host1 postfix.+RCPT from (?P<srcDns>.+)\[(?P<srcIp>[0-9\.]+)\]:.+blocked using (?P<blkList>.+)(?<=[a-z]);.+(https?:\/{2})?(?(5)(?P<entryUrl>.+)|.+)to=\<(?P<destEm>.+)>.+$
```

---

I'm sure the issue is my misunderstanding as to how the conditional statements and the `?` quantifier works.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your patterns, the email address for `to:` is between tags `<` and `>` but due to the formatting in the question they are not shown.

The parts in your pattern like `.+` first match until the end of the string, and will then backtrack and try to match the rest of the pattern.

You can make the pattern a bit more performant making the parts that you want and know more specific.

- For the datetime, you can make the pattern match the specified format instead of `.+` using `^(?P<datetime>[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\d{1,2}\s* \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})`
- For  `(?P<blkList>[^;]+)` and `(?P<entryUrl>[^;]+)` you can use a negated character class matching any char except `;`
- For group `(?P<destEm>[^<>\s]+)` you can exclude matching tags.
- To make match the url, instead of using a condition you can make the group optional using `?`

For example

```
^(?P<datetime>[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+\d{1,2}\s* \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) host1 postfix\b.*? RCPT from (?P<srcDns>.*?)\[(?P<srcIp>[0-9\.]+)\]:.*? blocked using (?P<blkList>[^;]+);(?:.+?https?:\/\/(?P<entryUrl>[^;]+);)?\s.*? to=[^<]*<(?P<destEm>[^<>\s]+)>
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/naN6s0/1).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to test your regex on page like [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/77ngJi/1)?
`to=\<(?P<destEm>.+)>` doesn't seem to match your examples. You should either remove `<>` or replace `to` with `helo`. Be careful to make your quantifier lazy after `blkList` otherwise you might catch too much text.
You can then make your url optional with `?` and it should work in both cases:

```
^(?P<datetime>.+) host1 postfix.+RCPT from (?P<srcDns>.+)\[(?P<srcIp>[0-9\.]+)\]:.+blocked using (?P<blkList>.+?);(.+https?:\/{2}(?P<entryUrl>.+);\s)?.+\sto=(?P<destEm>.+?)\s.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to replace in the first regex `.+https?:\/{2}(?P<entryUrl>.+);` with `(?:.+https?:\/{2}(?P<entryUrl>.+);)?` where `?:` indicates that it is a non-capturing group and the `?` at the end means that it is optional.

However, it still does not work because `.+` is greedy, so use lazy `.+?` instead.

Final regex:

```
^(?P<datetime>.+?) host1 postfix.+?RCPT from (?P<srcDns>.+?)\[(?P<srcIp>[0-9\.]+)\]:.+?blocked using (?P<blkList>.+?);(?:.+?https?:\/{2}(?P<entryUrl>.+?);)?\s.+?\sto=\<(?P<destEm>.+?)>.+?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/QkmXWz (to see it in action)